# Which testing tool can do REST and GUI?

Tags: rest, user-interface, automated-tests

We will soon be testing an application which provides a REST interface so my first idea was to use soapUI Pro as I have used it extensively for SOAP based applications. However I need a tool which can automate test for

- REST **and**
- GUI (Windows)

I can't go into detail but the application under test works basically like this:

1. A client sends several REST calls to the application.
2. On certain REST calls the application will show a GUI which needs to be automated as well.
3. The client continues with REST calls.

Currently I'm using soapUI Pro for REST and TestComplete for GUI testing but I need a tool which combines both.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio (for Testers, or Ultimate) has Web Tests (coded in C# and non-coded) that could hit your REST service, and UI Tests for GUI apps, that could fit the bill.

Web Tests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182538(v=VS.80).aspx

Coded UI Tests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx